# KeyListener or TraverseListener in SWT Menu

Tags: menu, swt, popupmenu

I'd like to be able to detect keyboard input (namely the TAB key) when an SWT menu is open, but it doesn't seem to broadcast any events when listeners are added with the `addListener` method, and there are no `addKeyListener` or `addTraverseListener` methods.

I've also tried adding listeners to the control to which the menu is added (it's a popup menu) as well as the shell, but key events don't make it to those objects either.

It looks like the menu is an OS level control that eats up keyboard events.  Has anyone found a way to grab keystrokes from a popup menu?  Or is the only option to make my own non-OS popup menu?

Comment: Can I ask what you are trying to accomplish by getting a notification when a traverses a menu?  Is there an action of some kind when this happens?

Comment: Sure.  I needed a more flexible table than the SWT Table or TableViewer widgets so I'm using a lightweight draw2D based table widget instead.  I want to be able to tab through cells in the table.  Some of the cells open a menu when they are activated.  In this state, there's no way to listen for the TAB key, close the menu, and move to the next cell without building my own non-OS menu or getting the OS-level handle of the menu and listening to OS-level events on it.

Comment: Hi, I am facing exact same issue. i want to close my context menu when user press F12. have anyone found any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the SWT menu is a native windowing-system menu. I'm not sure what you mean by the verb "traverse" in this context. Do you mean "hilight for possible selection"? I believe that, in SWT, that is called "arming", and you can indeed add listeners for arming events. See [this snippet](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/Updateastatuslinewhenanitemisarmed.htm).

If I've completely misunderstood your question, then let me know in a comment, and I'll delete.

Comment: When I say "traverse" I mean I want to close the menu and activate another control -- so traversing BETWEEN the menu and another widget, not WITHIN the menu widget.  I've never seen the "arm" event before, but I don't think it gets me where I want to go.